# LNK 2019 Ссылка на неразрешенный символ

Tags: c++

```
#include "Header.h" 

std::shared_ptr<Base> getPtr(char c)
{
    if (c == 'c') return std::make_shared<Voice>();
    else if (c == 'a') return std::make_shared<Data>();
}

class Assortment: public Base
{
public:
    Assortment() = default;
    ~Assortment() = default;

    void read(std::istream&);
    void print(std::ostream&);

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> TarifList;
private:
};

void Assortment::read(std::istream& in)
{
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        char c;
        in >> c;
        std::shared_ptr<Base> ptr = getPtr(c);
        ptr->read(in);
        TarifList.push_back(ptr);
    }
}
void Assortment::print(std::ostream& out)
{
    std::ostream_iterator<std::shared_ptr<Base>> _out(out);
    std::copy(TarifList.begin(), TarifList.end(), _out);
}
```

Данный код вызывает ошибку:

> Ошибка    LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "class
> std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits > & __cdecl
> operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits
> &,class std::shared_ptr)" (??6@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AEAV01@V?$shared_ptr@VBase@@@1@@Z)
> в функции "public: class std::ostream_iterator<class
> std::shared_ptr,char,struct std::char_traits > &
> __cdecl std::ostream_iterator<class std::shared_ptr,char,struct std::char_traits >::operator=(class
> std::shared_ptr const &)"
> (??4?$ostream_iterator@V?$shared_ptr@VBase@@@std@@DU?$char_traits@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@AEBV?$shared_ptr@VBase@@@1@@Z).    ConsoleApplication3 C:\Users\Fedor\Desktop\VisualStudio\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.obj 1